# VBA code to apply formatting and data validation macros to all worksheets except first three

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to the forum and VBA codes. I have been searching for an answer to this question and am completely lost. I have a workbook that contains around 36 worksheets. I have created a macro to apply conditional formatting and data validation to one sheet and have managed to combine these two into one macro; however I want to be able to run a macro to apply this to all sheets except the first three sheets (so to the other 33 sheets who all have different names). So far I have not had any luck. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQL7w.jpg)
I am not fussed how it works e.g. calling the combined macro code, calling the individual codes or calling the full codes, I have provided these below.

**Code for Conditional Formatting Macro**

```
`Sub Conditional_Formatting()
```

**Code for Data Validation Macro**

```
Sub Data_Validation()
```

Comment: Write an if() that tests the sheet name to a list: if there it is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site.

You can address and read excel sheets by their number `wb.sheets(1)` you don't have to use the name of the sheet.

So with that you could, in your loop, check if the number or Index is 1, 2 or 3.

```
if (sh.Index > 3) then
...
Your code
...
End if
```

where `sh` is the sheet reference.
This snip executes your code if the sheet index is greater than 3

Hope that makes sense.